# java download and save facebook image from url

Tags: java, facebook

I tried to save a facebook image from a url in java. This is my code:

```
try(InputStream in = new URL("http://graph.facebook.com/100001336637590/picture?width=2000&height=2000").openStream()){
        Files.copy(in, Paths.get("C:\\image.jpeg"));
    }
```

It saves me an image but it weighs 0 kb and when I open it come out a writing that says :"probably the file has an unsupported format".
Anyone could help me, thankyou.

Comment: That url has a bunch of redirections, that often includes empty body. Now, there are multiple ways to go. You can either follow the [redirections](https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-httpurlconnection-follow-redirect-example/), or you use the [final url](https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t31.0-1/c342.0.1365.1365/10582995_704759902911891_8368372731352065371_o.jpg?_nc_cat=105&oh=6ee4b870a1af29236f73f77a8d27ad0a&oe=5C14A5A2) to grab the image. Or maybe a third way.

Comment: Thankyou, I follow the redirctions and it works fine!